# How can we solve this problem? $\frac{2^{m + n} - 2^m - 1}{3} \in N$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

How can I solve this problem?

$$\frac{2^{m + n} - 2^m - 1}{3} \in N$$

Here, $m,n \in N$

I'm looking for all $(m,n)$ pair,which is the condition of the question.

Comment: Have you tried anything for solving this problem?

Comment: Of course. I have worked very hard...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

$\frac{2^{m+n}-2^m-1}{3}\in\mathbb{N}\Leftrightarrow 2^{m+n}-2^m-1\equiv 0\mod 3$

Therefore:

$2^m(2^n-1)-1\equiv 0\mod 3\Leftrightarrow (-1)^m((-1)^n+2)\equiv 1\mod 3$

$(-1)^n+2\equiv\begin{cases} 0\mod 3, \text{for n even}\\ 1\mod 3,\text{for n odd}\end{cases}$

So $n$ has to be odd and $m$ has to be even.

Comment: +1) Only solution is must be: $m$ is even and $n$ is odd. True?

Comment: Yes, therefore there are infinite many solutions. It has just to be $m=2k$ and $n=2l+1$ for $k,l\in\mathbb{N}$. For example m=2 and n=3, then $2^{3+2}-2^2-1=27$ and $3|27$. I tried to make every step as clear as possible. Are you familiar with this kind of arithmetic?

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately, I do not know. But, The last writting was very descriptive.

Comment: So you do not know, for example, why $2^m\equiv (-1)^m\mod 3$? Do you know what $\mod 3$ means? If not, we can think about more elementary proofs to help you.

Comment: I found pdf books on the internet. I will read. Thank you again :)

Comment: Feel free to ask if something is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

As $2\equiv-1\pmod3,2^m\equiv(-1)^m$

if $m$ is even
 $$2^{m+n}-2^m-1\equiv(-1)^n-1-1\pmod3\equiv(-1)^n+1$$

$\implies n$ must be odd.

If $m$ is odd, $$2^{m+n}-2^m-1\equiv-(-1)^n+1-1\pmod3\equiv(-1)^{n+1}$$

which clearly can not be $\equiv0\pmod3$

Comment: Please, can you write for me, for example: $m=2k-1$, $n=...$ ?

Comment: @I'mastudent, Please wait a bit

Comment: Then, $m=2p,n=2q-1$ is it true?..

Comment: @I'mastudent, where $p,$ are positive integers

Comment: Thank you professor. I understood.

Comment: @I'mastudent, Welcome! Sorry I'm also a student